# How to use React Query v4 SSR Hydration method with Next JS 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, react-query

Next JS 13 was just released last month and totally changed the way data was fetched while also providing an alternative to the use of _app.js and _document.js with the use of the root layout.js. Previously in Next JS 12 and below, to use the React Query SSR feature using the Hydration method, you needed to set your _app.js file like this:

```
import { Hydrate, QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import queryClientConfig from '../queryClientConfig';

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  const queryClient = useRef(new QueryClient(queryClientConfig));
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

  const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => page);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);

  if (!mounted) return null;

  return (
    <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={ErrorFallbackComponent}>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient.current}>
        <Hydrate state={pageProps.dehydratedState}>
          <AppProvider>
            {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}
          </AppProvider>
        </Hydrate>
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
}
```

To utilize React Query SSR in a page in Next JS using `getServerSideProps`, it goes like this:

```
// Packages
import Head from 'next/head';
import { dehydrate, QueryClient } from '@tanstack/react-query';

// Layout
import getDashboardLayout from '../../layouts/dashboard';


// Parse Cookies
import parseCookies from '../../libs/parseCookies';

// Hooks
import { useFetchUserProfile } from '../../hooks/user';
import { fetchUserProfile } from '../../hooks/user/api';
import { getGoogleAuthUrlForNewAccount } from '../../hooks/auth/api';
import { fetchCalendarsOnServer } from '../../hooks/event/api';
import { useFetchCalendars } from '../../hooks/event';


// Store
import useStaticStore from '../../store/staticStore';


// `getServerSideProps function`
export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
  const cookies = parseCookies(req);
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();

  try {
    await queryClient.prefetchQuery(['fetchUserProfile'], () =>
      fetchUserProfile(cookies.userAccessToken)
    );
    await queryClient.prefetchQuery(['fetchCalendars'], () => fetchCalendarsOnServer(cookies.userAccessToken));
    await queryClient.prefetchQuery(['getGoogleAuthUrlForNewAccount'], () =>
      getGoogleAuthUrlForNewAccount(cookies.userAccessToken)
    );
  } catch (error) {

  }

  return {
      props: {
        dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient),
      },
    };
}


function Home() {

  const {
    data: userProfileData, // This data is immediately made available without any loading as a result of the hydration and fetching that has occurred in `getServerSideProps`
    isLoading: isUserProfileDataLoading,
    error: userProfileDataError,
  } = useFetchUserProfile();

  const { data: savedCalendarsData } = useFetchCalendars(); // This data is immediately made available without any loading as a result of the hydration and fetching that has occurred in `getServerSideProps`

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>
          {userProfileData.data.firstName} {userProfileData.data.lastName} Dashboard
        </title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content={`${userProfileData.data.firstName} ${userProfileData.data.lastName} Dashboard`}
        />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <PageContentWrapper
      >
        Page Content
      </PageContentWrapper>
    </>
  );
}

Home.getLayout = getDashboardLayout; // This layout also needs data from userProfileData to be available. There is no problem and it never loads because the data is immediately available on mount.

export default Home;
```

Here is the old DashboardLayout component:

```
// Packages
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// Hooks
import { useFetchUserProfile } from '../../hooks/user';

DashboardLayout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

function DashboardLayout({ children }) {

  const { isLoading, error, data: userProfileData } = useFetchUserProfile(); // Data is immediately available and never loads because it has been fetched using SSR in getServerSideProps

 
  if (isLoading)
    return (
      <div className="w-screen h-screen flex items-center justify-center text-white text-3xl font-medium">
        Loading...
      </div>
    );

  if (error) {
    return (
      <div className="w-screen h-screen flex items-center justify-center text-brand-red-300 text-3xl font-medium">
        {error.message}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="the-dashboard-layout">
        {/* Start of Main Page */}

        <p className="mb-2 text-brand-gray-300 text-sm leading-5 font-normal">
          <span className="capitalize">{`${userProfileData.data.firstName}'s`}</span> Layout
        </p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default function getDashboardLayout(page) {
  return <DashboardLayout>{page}</DashboardLayout>;
}
```

Using the new Next JS 13, there is no way to use the React Query Hydration method and even when I am able to fetch the data using the new method, the data is still refetched when the component mounts which causes the layout to be in a loading state as the data is not immediately available.

In Next 13, you only need to call the data fetching method and pass it to the client components directly because the app directory now supports server components directly.

First of all, a root layout file replaces the old _app.js and _document.js file in Next 13: It is important to note that there is no `pageProps` object anymore for the `dehydratedState`.

Here is the `RootLayout` server component:

```
// Packages
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// Components
import RootLayoutClient from './root-layout-client';

RootLayout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <RootLayoutClient>{children}</RootLayoutClient>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Here is the `RootLayoutClient` client component for the layout needed because of the use of Context and State which are client-side operations:

```
'use client';

// Packages
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// Context
import { AppProvider } from '../contexts/AppContext';

// Config
import queryClientConfig from '../queryClientConfig';

RootLayoutClient.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

export default function RootLayoutClient({ children }) {

  const queryClient = useRef(new QueryClient(queryClientConfig));
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);

  if (!mounted) return null;

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient.current}>
      <AppProvider>
         {children}
      </AppProvider>
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}
```

`getServerSideProps` method has now been replaced with normal Promise based data fetching method using the FETCH API. The fetched data returned can now passed into the page/component that needs it.

Here is my data fetching function:

```
import { getCookie } from 'cookies-next';

export const fetchUserProfile = async (token) => {
  if (token) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EXTERNAL_API_URL + FETCH_USER_PROFILE_URL, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
      } else {
        Promise.reject(response);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      Promise.reject(error);
    }
  } else {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EXTERNAL_API_URL + FETCH_USER_PROFILE_URL, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${getCookie('userAccessToken')}`,
        },
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
      } else {
        Promise.reject(response);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      Promise.reject(error);
    }
  }
};
```

Here is how the data is fetched and used in the home page. Note that the home page resides in the app directory: `home/page.js`:

```
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

// Hooks
import { fetchUserProfile } from '../../../hooks/user/api';

// Components
import HomeClient from './home-client';

export default async function Page() {
  const nextCookies = cookies();
  const userAccessToken = nextCookies.get('accessToken');

  const userProfileData = await fetchUserProfile(userAccessToken.value);


// This is essentially prop passing which was not needed using the previous hydration and getServerSideProps methods.
// Now, I have to pass this data down to a client component called `HomeClient` that needs the data. This is done because I may need to  perform some client-side operations on the component.

  return <HomeClient userData={userProfileData} />;
}
```

Here is the `HomeClient` client component:

```
'use client';

import { useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// Hooks
import { useFetchUserProfile } from '../../hooks/user';


HomeClient.propTypes = {
  userData: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  calendarData: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
};

export default function HomeClient({ userData }) {

const { isLoading, error, data: userProfileData } = useFetchUserProfile();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(userData));
  }, [userData]);
  
  // This now loads instead of being immediately available. This can be mitigated by directly using the userData passed
  // through props but I don't want to engage in prop drilling in case I need it to be passed into deeper nested child components
  
  if (isLoading) {
    return (
        <div>Loading...</div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <>
      <AnotherChildComponent profileData={userProfileData.data.profile}/>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is the useFetchUserProfile hook function used in `HomeClient` client component above:

```
export const useFetchUserProfile = (conditional = true) => {
// Used to be immediately available as a result of the key 'fetchUserProfile' being used to fetch data on getServerSideProps but that's not available in the app directory

  return useQuery(['fetchUserProfile'], () => fetchUserProfile(), {
    enabled: conditional,
    cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 5,
  });
};
```

Here is the parent `layout.js` file required by NextJS 13 to share a common layout. This `layout.js` also needs the fetched data but there is no way to pass the data to this even through `props`. In the past, Data was immediately available here because of the `react-query` hydration performed in `getServerSideProps`

```
// Packages
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// Hooks
import { useFetchUserProfile } from '../../hooks/user';

DashboardLayout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

function DashboardLayout({ children }) {

  const { isLoading, error, data: userProfileData } = useFetchUserProfile(); 
  // Used to be that data was immediately available and never loaded because it has been fetched using SSR in getServerSideProps
  // Now, it has to load the same data. This is even more complex because props can't be passed as there is no way or any abstraction method 
  // to share data between the layout and child components
  


  if (isLoading)
    return (
      <div className="w-screen h-screen flex items-center justify-center text-white text-3xl font-medium">
        Loading...
      </div>
    );

  if (error) {
    return (
      <div className="w-screen h-screen flex items-center justify-center text-brand-red-300 text-3xl font-medium">
        {error.message}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="the-dashboard-layout">
        {/* Start of Main Page */}

        <p className="mb-2 text-brand-gray-300 text-sm leading-5 font-normal">
          <span className="capitalize">{`${userProfileData.data.firstName}'s`}</span> Layout
        </p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

How can I de-duplicate the multiple requests being made and make the data available in all components that fetch the same data without prop-drilling?
And how do I also get around the limitation of not being able to pass the data to the parent layout components even if I wanted to use props.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: so you aren't really showing the code you used to do this with next13, because getServerSideProps doesn't exist in the app directory. there is no way to answer this if you're only showing next12 code ...

Comment: @TkDodo I have edited my question to include that now. Please take a look

Comment: pass the `userData` as `initialData` to `useQuery`

Comment: @TkDodo, that means I have to do that in every component that uses that particular useQuery. Isn't that just like passing the props of the data fetched to every component that needs it? Thank you very much for your help, I will do that. As a co-maintainer of `react-query`, when do you think react-query will update their methods and docs to support the new Next 13 way of doing things using the same Hydration method that used to work so well?

Comment: @TkDodo, on further thinking, I am thinking of storing the user data when it is fetched into the context api and then passing it as initial data into any component that may need it instead of prop drilling. What do you think?

Comment: Imo hydration was a necessary by-product because we couldn't fetch where we needed to. in gSSP, we fetched 5 things in parallel and then used them in 3 different components on the client. That worked, but I'd rather fetch directly in the 3 components, or at least in a server component near it. I think the initialData way should work most of the time. we have an open PR for the docs: https://github.com/TanStack/query/pull/4568

Comment: Oh alright. @TkDodo, I will go with the initialData method for now. I tried the hydration method defined in the docs PR but it seems hacky and doesn't really work for me. Thank you for your help